# Get Private Key from BouncyCastle X509 Certificate? C#

Tags: c#, x509certificate, bouncycastle, private-key

Normally when I grab an `X509Certificate2` out of my keystore I can call `.PrivateKey` to retrieve the cert's private key as an `AsymmetricAlgorithm`. However I have decided to use Bouncy Castle and its instance of `X509Certificate` only has a `getPublicKey();` I cannot see a way to get the private key out of the cert. Any ideas?

I get the an X509Certificate2 from my Windows-MY keystore then use:

```
//mycert is an X509Certificate2 retrieved from Windows-MY Keystore
X509CertificateParser certParser = new X509CertificateParser();
X509Certificate privateCertBouncy = certParser.ReadCertificate(mycert.GetRawCertData());
AsymmetricKeyParameter pubKey = privateCertBouncy.GetPublicKey();
//how do i now get the private key to make a keypair?
```

Is there anyway to convert a `AsymmetricAlgorithm`(C# private key) to a `AsymmetricKeyParameter`(bouncycastle private key)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Don't know BouncyCastle that much but it seems to me that the simple thing to do is to recreate the key based on the key parameters.

```
public static AsymmetricKeyParameter TransformRSAPrivateKey(
    AsymmetricAlgorithm privateKey)
{
    RSACryptoServiceProvider prov = privateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
    RSAParameters parameters = prov.ExportParameters(true);
    
    return new RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters(
        new BigInteger(1,parameters.Modulus),
        new BigInteger(1,parameters.Exponent),
        new BigInteger(1,parameters.D),
        new BigInteger(1,parameters.P),
        new BigInteger(1,parameters.Q),
        new BigInteger(1,parameters.DP),
        new BigInteger(1,parameters.DQ),
        new BigInteger(1,parameters.InverseQ));
}
```

You can call the code by using

```
AsymmetricKeyParameter bouncyCastlePrivateKey = 
    TransformRSAPrivateKey(mycert.PrivateKey);
```

Obviously this assumes that the certificate includes a RSA Key but the same result can be achieved for DSA with `DSACryptoServiceProvider` and `DSAParameters`.

Answer (score 34):

```
Akp = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(this.Certificate.PrivateKey).Private;
```

Comment: Doing this I just get  ```Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper.WindowsCryptographicException: 'The requested operation is not supported.'```

Answer (score 3):

Find .NET X509Certificate2:

```
X509Certificate2 cert = this.FindCertificate(certificateFriendlyName);
```

Parse it to BouncyCastle certificate and use X509Certificate2Signature to get signature:

```
var parser = new X509CertificateParser();
var bouncyCertificate = parser.ReadCertificate(cert.RawData);
var algorithm = DigestAlgorithms.GetDigest(bouncyCertificate.SigAlgOid);
var signature = new X509Certificate2Signature(cert, algorithm);
```

Comment: This is not working for EC Elliptic Curve  private key