# BouncyCastle create AsymmetricCipherKeyPair from existing keys?

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, pki, private-key

I have two `AssymetricAlgorithm` RSA keys that I have pulled out of a certificate that was in my keystore. One is the Public Key and the other the Private. Is there a way of getting this keypair into a BouncyCastle AsymmetricCipherKeyPair? BouncyCastle's `AsymmetricCipherKeyPair` expects a public and private `AsymmetricKeyParameter` however I have no way of getting my Private key without it being an instance of `AssymetricAlgorithm`.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240222/get-private-key-from-bouncycastle-x509-certificate-c for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this lies here:

[Get Private Key from BouncyCastle X509 Certificate? C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240222/get-private-key-from-bouncycastle-x509-certificate-c)

Comment: I suspect a better answer lies in the Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities class

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help if key is marked as exportable

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider key = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)X509Certificate2object.PrivateKey;
RSAParameters rsaparam = key.ExportParameters(true);
AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keypair = DotNetUtilities.GetRsaKeyPair(rsaparam);
```